# Android: "Cannot Resolve symbol 'addValueEventListener'" in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-contentresolver

I've tried importing a variety of Firebase packages to stop this error from occurring, but it still persists. I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
   firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

but I'm consistently getting the error:

```
Cannot Resolve symbol 'addValueEventListener'
```

despite the fact I have ValueEventListener imported. (It might be important to note that ValueEventListener is displayed in the IDE as an unused import, even though I'm clearly attempting to use it)

Comment: `firebase` must be a `Query` or `DatabaseReference`

Comment: firebase is a Query

Comment: Copy and paste these statements.  Do you see the same error message? `Query q = null; q.addValueEventListener(null);`

Comment: Yes, I get the same error

Comment: And you have this import? `import com.google.firebase.database.Query`

Comment: Yes, and it says it's being used. I also have the import "   com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;" which still says it's being unused

Comment: Can't see the problem.  Try clicking on `Query` and then hitting Ctrl-B to open the decompiled class file.  If you scroll down a page, do you you see a method declaration for `addValueEventListener()`?

Comment: Yes, I see a method declaration for addValueEventListener(). It also might be notable that ValueEventListener itself it working, it's just addValueEventListener() that isn't being recognized.

Comment: @BobSnyder However, even when I try to use ValueEventListener, it says my import is unused

Comment: I can only guess that something is corrupted in your Android Studio environment.  Try doing a clean build, clearing caches, restarting AS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are instantiating and adding the method inside a method such as OnStart(){} or the constructor of the class you are working in. If it is not it will behave similar to how you describe.

An Example of this issue :

```
public class ReadFromFireBase(){

 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

public ReadFromFireBase(){
}

ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mDataBase.addValueEventListener(postListener);




}
```

This will not work and throw errors similar to what you are getting, it is an easy mistake to make given the way the listener is structured

The proper way would be something such as :

```
public class ReadFromFireBase(){

 private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
 private ValueEventListener postListener;


   public ReadFromFireBase(){
   postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mDataBase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
}






}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.firebase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
```

Import these packages andyour error will be solved.