# What is the correct library for Firebase's addValueEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using multiple different imports with Firebase:

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
```

however, when I try to do

```
query.addValueEventListener
```

It doesn't recognize addValueEventListener. I've tried remaking the project and invalidating caches and restarting, but I'm still getting this error. What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The appearance of this:

```
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
```

indicates you are including the legacy Firebase SDK along with the "new" SDK.  Not a good practice.  Best to update your build.gradle dependencies to eliminate:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.x.x'
```

If there are places in your code where you are using the legacy API, you can use the hints in the [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) to migrate to the new API.

This should also resolve your [other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43750662/4815718).

Comment: So you're saying I should delete "compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.x.x'" and replace it with what?

Comment: You must already have `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:x.x.x`, so you don't need to replace anything.

Comment: I deleted that line, remade the project, invalidated caches and restarted, and it's still not recognizing addValueEventListener

Comment: @2____: Check your imports to ensure there is nothing that starts with `com.firebase.client`.  If you find any, delete them.

Comment: I deleted all instances of com.firebase.client, and it's still not recognizing addValueEventListener. It's also not recognizing addListenerForSingleValueEvent or any other method of Query

Comment: Post your module build.gradle file